# Is there a way to get the arguments supplied to a php function?

Tags: php

Is there a way to get the parameters passed to a php function?

fill in the blank if its possible:

```
function foo(){
    var_dump( SOME_MAGICAL_FUNCTION_THAT_GETS_ALL_PARAMETERS_INTO_AN_ARRAY );
}
foo('a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[func_get_args()](http://php.net/func_get_args) does exactly that.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, with PHP's in-built function [func_get_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

Here is an example from the PHP documentation:

```
function foo()
{
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    echo "Number of arguments: $numargs<br />\n";
    if ($numargs >= 2) {
        echo "Second argument is: " . func_get_arg(1) . "<br />\n";
    }
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        echo "Argument $i is: " . $arg_list[$i] . "<br />\n";
    }
}

foo(1, 2, 3);
```